Как создать транзакцию в Nbitcoin C#
Ошибка транзакции Nbitcoin C#
Я использую Push на https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/pushtx/, выдает ошибку   Error validating transaction: Error running script for input 0  referencing  b9ea9fa41f777485d5559f8cbfef696519c6b5c53a635fdd5733c7ceabd496f5 at 0:  Script was NOT verified successfully.. .
using NBitcoin;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var senderPrivateKey = "cUL1cmQ6JxezE8mkatq8zc2YQY2eYKMpTxSxGzLERsGtKkicENjB";
        var senderAddress = "tb1qe3d3h5g6exnwtu83sdafsu6sajp0paz4ss7ne5";
        var receiverAddress = "tb1pr7h57eru4pqpksspw24vjn7kucyddnezhh23hd9dmu4vs9ksgfdqv7hejc";

        var transactionHex = CreateAndSignTransaction(senderPrivateKey, senderAddress, receiverAddress);
        Console.WriteLine("Transaction Hex: " + transactionHex);
    }

    static string CreateAndSignTransaction(string senderPrivateKey, string senderAddress, string receiverAddress)
    {
        var network = Network.TestNet;
        var tx = Transaction.Create(network);

        var receiverBitcoinAddress = BitcoinAddress.Create(receiverAddress, network);
        var amountToSend = Money.Coins(0.00001m);
        var changeBitcoinAddress = BitcoinAddress.Create(senderAddress, network);
        var changeScriptPubKey = changeBitcoinAddress.ScriptPubKey;

        var totalInputAmount = Money.Zero;
        var inputs = GetUnspentOutputs(senderAddress);
        foreach (var input in inputs)
        {
            var outPoint = input.Outpoint;
            var txIn = new TxIn(outPoint);

            // Создаем скрипт подписи
            var secret = new BitcoinSecret(senderPrivateKey, network);
            var publicKey = secret.GetAddress(ScriptPubKeyType.Segwit);
            var witScriptPubKey = publicKey.ScriptPubKey;
            txIn.ScriptSig = Script.Empty;

            tx.Inputs.Add(txIn);

            var coin = new Coin(outPoint, new TxOut(input.Amount, witScriptPubKey));
            tx.Sign(secret, coin);

            totalInputAmount += input.Amount;
        }

        // Создаем выходы
        tx.Outputs.Add(amountToSend, receiverBitcoinAddress.ScriptPubKey);

        var changeAmount = totalInputAmount - amountToSend;
        if (changeAmount > Money.Zero)
        {
            tx.Outputs.Add(changeAmount, changeScriptPubKey);
        }

        return tx.ToHex();
    }

    static List<(OutPoint Outpoint, Money Amount, int Confirmation)> GetUnspentOutputs(string bitcoinAddress)
    {
        string url = $"https://blockstream.info/testnet/api/address/{bitcoinAddress}/utxo";

        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            string json = client.DownloadString(url);
            dynamic data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

            var utxos = new List<(OutPoint Outpoint, Money Amount, int Confirmation)>();
            foreach (var utxo in data)
            {
                OutPoint outpoint = new OutPoint(uint256.Parse((string)utxo["txid"]), (int)utxo["vout"]);
                Money amount = Money.Coins((decimal)utxo["value"]);
                int confirmation = utxo["confirmations"] != null ? (int)utxo["confirmations"] : 0;

                utxos.Add((outpoint, amount, confirmation));
            }

            return utxos;
        }
    }
}

Hex code транзакции
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

Decoded Transaction

{
    "addresses": [
        "tb1pr7h57eru4pqpksspw24vjn7kucyddnezhh23hd9dmu4vs9ksgfdqv7hejc",
        "tb1qe3d3h5g6exnwtu83sdafsu6sajp0paz4ss7ne5"
    ],
    "block_height": -1,
    "block_index": -1,
    "confirmations": 0,
    "double_spend": false,
    "fees": 0,
    "hash": "a66f11acd8693d2e6e409bbb2acdeb594a2abaa9b02ba1b6152e4f033a187954",
    "inputs": [
        {
            "addresses": [
                "tb1qe3d3h5g6exnwtu83sdafsu6sajp0paz4ss7ne5"
            ],
            "age": 2811605,
            "output_index": 0,
            "output_value": 17822,
            "prev_hash": "b9ea9fa41f777485d5559f8cbfef696519c6b5c53a635fdd5733c7ceabd496f5",
            "script_type": "pay-to-witness-pubkey-hash",
            "sequence": 4294967295,
            "witness": [
                "304402205be63509a16454894cac972ac924963f91e39eee22aff359c8bde339547c80e20220207ada38474d4c560416c8a87c5424707a5e97c6aa1b807c0d076cdabf4f043201",
                "0258556d400f25ebf63aae5a3b730f856d59da6a4a02ace582ba51e3b17ce7019e"
            ]
        },
        {
            "addresses": [
                "tb1qe3d3h5g6exnwtu83sdafsu6sajp0paz4ss7ne5"
            ],
            "age": 2811350,
            "output_index": 1,
            "output_value": 11765,
            "prev_hash": "a0c73dc3588ea03521cb71644d6a65e7359a2f47980dacbaa2fe46d45575f647",
            "script_type": "pay-to-witness-pubkey-hash",
            "sequence": 4294967295,
            "witness": [
                "30440220421cbf183e88b03df45e7aa3f10a7d80ae7acfd34a6e307ec3fae304b774a2c7022031e38907fcf32517437a31edddfe0f1c53409d278985dcff166d32dc355bbff801",
                "0258556d400f25ebf63aae5a3b730f856d59da6a4a02ace582ba51e3b17ce7019e"
            ]
        },
        {
            "addresses": [
                "tb1qe3d3h5g6exnwtu83sdafsu6sajp0paz4ss7ne5"
            ],
            "age": 2812672,
            "output_index": 0,
            "output_value": 14862,
            "prev_hash": "185866e80c946218663dbe8c56a717ba6c96f245e2ba2bdd06178a5000efc374",
            "script_type": "pay-to-witness-pubkey-hash",
            "sequence": 4294967295,
            "witness": [
                "30440220628e0279ba7bfcd1ecce55ad85daf7eb71d4fceb5178ff9cd33a69742804c52a02202f3f3e23c8978565ea3dc50621fe6c5e1624ab6fc6301dff869365b7ce647bba01",
                "0258556d400f25ebf63aae5a3b730f856d59da6a4a02ace582ba51e3b17ce7019e"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "outputs": [
        {
            "addresses": [
                "tb1pr7h57eru4pqpksspw24vjn7kucyddnezhh23hd9dmu4vs9ksgfdqv7hejc"
            ],
            "script": "51201faf4f647ca8401b420172aac94fd6e608d6cf22bdd51bb4addf2ac816d0425a",
            "script_type": "pay-to-taproot",
            "value": 1000
        },
        {
            "addresses": [
                "tb1qe3d3h5g6exnwtu83sdafsu6sajp0paz4ss7ne5"
            ],
            "script": "0014cc5b1bd11ac9a6e5f0f1837a987350ec82f0f455",
            "script_type": "pay-to-witness-pubkey-hash",
            "value": 4444899999000
        }
    ],
    "preference": "low",
    "received": "2024-05-07T14:27:18.849612491Z",
    "relayed_by": "34.235.155.234",
    "size": 530,
    "total": 4444900000000,
    "ver": 1,
    "vin_sz": 3,
    "vout_sz": 2,
    "vsize": 288
}


Версия .NET какая? Используете устаревшие классы. По самому вопросу - в чём угодно может быть проблема. Я погуглил, от неверного публичного ключа до отсуствия транзакции за комиссию на перевод.

senderPrivateKey - вы уверены, что это публичная информация и её может читать любой желающий?
